# UVA 369-Combinations | Modular Arithmetic | Binary Exponentiation

Tags: java, algorithm, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve uVa's 369(Combinations) problem using Modular Arthimetic and Binary Exponentiation instead of just using BigInteger class in java. I am able to pass the last two base test cases but not the first test case. Can anybody explain where my code is wrong ?

```
public class Main {
    static long M = 1000000007;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true){
            String s = br.readLine();
            s = s.trim();
            s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");
            String[] str = s.split(" ");
            long n = Long.parseLong(str[0]);
            long m = Long.parseLong(str[1]);
            if(n == 0 && m == 0) break;
            long a = fact(n); long b = fact((n-m) % M); long c = fact(m);
            long d = (b*c) % M;
            long ans = divide(a,d);
            System.out.println(n + " things taken " + m + " at a time is " + ans + " exactly");
        }
    }
    public static long fact(long N){
        long ans = 1;
        for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i)
            ans = (ans * i) % M;
        return ans;
    }
    public static long divide(long a, long b){
        return a * pow(b,M-2) % M;
    }
    public static long pow(long a, long b){
        long res = 1;
        while(b > 0){
            if(b % 2 == 1) res = (res*a) % M;
            a = (a*a) % M;
            b /=2;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M` is too small. For example for the input `100 6`, the correct result is 1192052400, but since your code works modulo 1000000007 the result will be 1192052400 mod 1000000007 = 192052393, which is much smaller (not just 7 smaller).

Using `M = 0x7fffffff` (also a prime) may work.

Comment: How did you decide which next big prime to take ?

Comment: @AbhishekDasgupta I took the biggest prime that fits in an `int` so that a product between two values would fit in a `long` (an other common problem is having overflow there) and also small enough that the product would be non-negative (to avoid the weird things that happen in Java when you mod a negative number)